# Point out the current DOM class being used in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am struck in a problem, where I need to point out the current number of the class I am using in JS. For example here is my code:

```
<div>
<p class="child"><button type="submit" onclick="myfunction()">Click here</button></p>
<p class="child"><button type="submit" onclick="myfunction()">Click here</button></p>
<p class="child"><button type="submit" onclick="myfunction()">Click here</button></p>
<p class="child"><button type="submit" onclick="myfunction()">Click here</button></p>
</div>
```

Now I know if I type `document.getElementsByClassName("child")`, it will provide me an array with all the able usage of class p mentioned. However I want to know the exact button which was clicked.

Like if the second button p class was clicked, I want my function to return me the number 2. Similarly if the third button was clicked, I want the number 3 returned to me. Is there any function for that? How should I proceed? I am completely new to JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called **Event Delegation** in javascript. You just add the event listener on the parent element in order to avoid having to add event handlers to multiple child elements.

`e.target` gives you the element on which the event handler (here click) was called on. You can get info regarding that element using various properties like `e.target.textContent` gives you the button text.

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container")

container.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
  console.log(e.target)
  console.log(e.target.textContent)
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p><button type="button">Click here 1</button></p>
  <p><button type="button">Click here 2</button></p>
  <p><button type="button">Click here 3</button></p>
  <p><button type="button">Click here 4</button></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, however, what I want is the number which was clicked. For example if when you document.getElementsByClassName, you get an array containing 4 objects. What I want is to point out which button was clicked that initiated the function. For example, if second button was clicked, I want '2' as an answer.

Comment: @Insignificant_guy just an FYI.  This would use the same concept as in the other answers.  This one might be closer to the one I gave you, but he gist is the same.  The only difference is in the way he bound the event, which is for the most part an improvement and the way some libraries would handle the event under the covers.  But unless you are doing a more serious project, for example where event performance might become a problem (that this would address), you're better off just doing what's easier or more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `this` to the function, which is the current element.
I've added code to find all `.child` elements, and find the index that matches this button's parent, and then alert it.
I would recommend using `addEventListener` instead of onclick attributes.
Depending on what you are doing, I'd recommend adding `data="n"` attributes added to the DOM elements, or an object map of values.  But this will work as is:

```js
function myfunction(el){
   const index = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('child'))
                      .findIndex(x=>x===el.parentNode);
   alert(index);
}
```

```html
<div>
<p class="child"><button type="submit" onclick="myfunction(this)">Click here</button></p>
<p class="child"><button type="submit" onclick="myfunction(this)">Click here</button></p>
<p class="child"><button type="submit" onclick="myfunction(this)">Click here</button></p>
<p class="child"><button type="submit" onclick="myfunction(this)">Click here</button></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the list of elements having this class, add the event listener to each item, so you can access the number inside the function normally. Here is an example:

```js
let childs = document.getElementsByClassName('child');
for(let i = 0; i < childs.length; i++){
      let el = childs[i];
      el.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            console.log(i+1);
      });
}
```

```html
<div>
     <p class="child"><button type="submit">Click here 1</button></p>
     <p class="child"><button type="submit">Click here 2</button></p>
     <p class="child"><button type="submit">Click here 3</button></p>
     <p class="child"><button type="submit">Click here 4</button></p>
</div>
```